# Is threre a way to import 'environment.ts' file to json?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular9

In my angular app, I require to import the assets according to the `env` config. for that, I am trying to download the patch from `environment.ts` to my assets `json` file. but have no clue, is there a way to do this? if we can't import directly what is the correct way to do this?

here is my try:

```
assets/db.json =>
{
  "url":"some url"
}
```

environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  "url":"env.url"
}
```

[Live Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/cpNNiHUe2ulIS7ak?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1)

Answer (score 1):

Angular has an option as `resolveJsonModule` which is setting at `(tsconfig || tsconfig.app).json`

To do it:

*tsconfig.json*

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    ...
   }
```

*environment.ts*

```
import * as db from "<pathofJson>/<fileName>.json"

export const environment = {
  url: db.url
}
```

Comment: @nevatopcu - guess you miss understood. I would like to get the base url from env.ts to assets json file. is there any way for it?